# How to pull single file from multiple similar named file using sftp

Tags: remote, sftp, file-server

I want to pull a single file from multiple similar named file using sftp.

Eg. if my remote server is having below files,

```
file_0722_005.dat
file_0722_020.dat
file_0722_033.dat
file_0722_0022.dat
```

I just want to pull any one among them.

In unix I can go for

```
ls file_0722_*|head -1
```

But in sftp head/tail won't work.

Please suggest how can this be done!

Comment: Why not execute the command with `head` remotely via ssh?

Comment: SFTP (or plain FTP) is a protocol that can be implemented on ***any*** operating system and in no way linked to Unix.  The only thing minimally relevant here is the comparison you make with a Unix shell command but your question remains off-topic.

Comment: I need to pull the file from remote server using sftp and ssh to the server is not allowed! Even I can't use ssh to pull the file.

Comment: Since you're not even dealing with a shell script, why don't you just choose the file manually?

Comment: Are we talking about https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SSH_File_Transfer_Protocol ? If so, how can you use SFTP but not SSH?

Comment: @schaiba, it's common to have `ssh` deployment where only sftp (as opposed to running arbitrary shell commands or doing port redirections...) is enabled.

Comment: The only option you have, is tab completion. Nothing else works.

Answer (score 2):

[SSHFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SSHFS) lets you mount a remote filesystem on your local machine. It relies on SFTP as the communication protocol, so if the server allows SFTP, you can use SSHFS. Your client machine must support [FUSE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_in_Userspace) which is the case of most modern Unix variants, including Linux, OSX, *BSD, and Solaris.

```
mkdir myserver
sshfs username@server.example.com:/path/to/directory myserver
cd myserver
set file_0722_*
cp "$1" /local/directory
fusermount -u myserver
```

Answer (score 1):

You could get a different client.

For instance with `lftp` (`lftp sftp://user@host/dir`):

```
glob eval -f 'get "$0"' file_0722_*
```

However, you cannot use that if file names may contain backslash, double quote or newline characters. If you don't have control over the names of the files, then it becomes a command injection vulnerability (for instance, a file named `file_0722_";!reboot"` would make you run the `reboot` command).